# Async API call Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, angular-httpclient

I have a quick question to call async API data from "http://3.35.241.42" which is given for testing a API

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";



@Component({
  selector: 'app-deposit',
  templateUrl: './deposit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deposit.component.scss']
})
export class DepositComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  datas = [];
  apiUrl = "http://3.35.241.42";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data => {
      this.datas = data;
      console.log(this.datas);
    })
  }
```

In html,

```
<button (click) = "getData()"></button>
<p>{{ datas | json }}</p>
```

What I just want to do is to call the API data which show me only one string to test I am doing right way.

But, it gave me an empty list for it.

Is there any way to do it?

Errors what I got is below!

1. > ":4200/#/deposit:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://3.35.241.42/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
2. > "3.35.241.42/:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED"
3. > "ERROR HttpErrorResponseerror: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}message: "Http failure response for http://3.35.241.42: 0 Unknown Error"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 0statusText: "Unknown Error"url: "http://3.35.241.42"**proto**: HttpResponseBase
   > defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.js:66361"

Comment: Please provide more details like when getData() function is triggered?

Comment: The question isn't clear at the moment. Please explain what exactly the issue is. Do you get a response? Is it an unexpected response?

Comment: Hey! thanks for comment, what do you mean when I am calling getData()?

Comment: @MichaelD Opps, Sorry about that, I am about to upload error what I got

Comment: @MichaelD I uploaded the errors what I got!

Comment: When does your function get execute?

Comment: @yazan Hey! I added the button above as well as the errors what I got

Comment: You have a backend issue you have to enable CORS in your REST Controller to fetch data from the API